# See which Python class is using my 100% CPU?

Tags: python, performance, pymongo, tweepy

I'm running a python script with a few imported classes (like Tweepy and PyMongo). I'm running into performance issues (aka clogging at 100% of CPU). I'd like to know which of my Python classes are resonsible!

Is that possible?

(Detailed description of my issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698949/efficiency-when-inserting-into-mongodb-pymongo).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very possible to do via a [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29).

A profiler basically runs your code and saves statistics about it while doing so. For instance which functions call which and how long each call takes etc.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script) for a bit more info.